# You don't have permission to access this resource.Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, cpanel, cpanel-uapi

I wanted to updated my Wordpress site, before updating I took backup for the entire website folder and so I installed an updated theme but later I decided to remove the update by deleting the whole website folder and put back the backup folder. after that I get this error

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

my site is [Business Directory in Tanzania](https://bizyciti.com)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you sorted out your htaccess issue, as I can see your website loading.

But, as it stands now, a lot of your static assets (css and images) aren't loading.

Seems some type of an issue with your Amazon Cloudfront configuration - I'd clear the Amazon cache and see if that resolves it.

If not, turn it off, and try to debug

Comment: the problem was with missing database

Comment: Brilliant - glad you figured it out

Answer (score 0):

I checked the data base on myphpadmin and I found out it was deleted, so I created another one with same credentials like on wp-config, and now it works fine. Thanks much